# PatternSyntaxException while using string,match()

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting a pattern syntax exception in this regular expression:

```
[^c]*[c]{freq}[^c]*
```

It checks for the multiple occurrence of the letter `C` (equal to frequency or amount of times).

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Tell us sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `freq` variable in regex like this. Build your regex as a String:

```
String regex = "[^c]*c{" + freq + "}[^c]*";
```

If `c` is also a variable then use:

```
String regex = "[^" + c + "]*" + c + "{" + freq + "}[^" + c + "]*";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK7sM3/1)

Comment: this solves the error but i cant get the correct out put...can you help @anubhava ? What is wrong with this regular expression..?

Comment: yes .. 2 appears consecutively at least twice wg:  22 or 122 or 222 or 220

Comment: here c and freq are variables ...  which are defined by user.. so c=2 and freq=2 as well..srry should have mentioned..

Comment: ya thnx its working...it clicked to to me as well.!!

Comment: Is there a way to check these regular expression on numbers without converting them into Strings...with String.matches() or is there any other function for that..?

Comment: I know..but in a java program we have to convert a number to string in order to check or use string.matches(regex) .. is there any way we can directly check the integer or number to the regex..in java..?

Comment: In Java code `String#matches` is the simplest method to check a regex